# Show images in order of buttons clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to web developing and trying to build a website that shows different flags when clicking buttons.

I encounter some problems when positioning the image... For example, when I click "C -> A -> D -> B ->A", the A flag shows up before other flags and I cannot click again to make it show up twice. Here are my questions.

1) When I click the buttons the images show up in the order of the , not by which button I click first. Is there any way to make the first click one shows up first?

2) What function or code in CSS/javascript/JQuery I can use if I want the image to show up twice or for more times?

Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>

<script>
function showImg( id ) {
        for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        }
        var obj = document.getElementById( "flag" + id );      
        if (obj != null)
            obj.className = 'show';
}


</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .hide{display:none;}
</style>


<input type="button" onclick="showImg(1)" value="A" >

<input type="button" onclick="showImg(2)" value="B">

<input type="button" onclick="showImg(3)" value= "C">

<input type="button" onclick = "showImg(4)" value= "D">

<input type="button" onclick = "showImg(5)" value= "E">

<input type="button" onclick = "showImg(6)" value= "ANS">

<div class="row">
  <div class="main">
   <div class="screen" position: relative">
    <img id="flag1" src="flag1.jpeg" title="1" class="hide" position="static">
   </div>
   <div position= "relative">
       <img id="flag2" src="lag2.jpeg" title="2" class="hide">

            <div position= "relative">
       <img id="flag3" src="flag3.jpeg" title="3" class="hide">
            </div>
            <div position= "relative">
       <img id="flag4" src="flag4.jpeg" title="4" class="hide">
            </div>
            <div position= "relative">
       <img id="flag5" src="flag5.jpeg" title="5" class="hide">
            </div>
      <div position= "relative">
    <img id="flag6" src="flag6.jpeg" class="hide" position="static">
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The images will show up in the order which the appear in the HTML document. You have the order of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 so thats the order they will render in. You should try dynamically injecting them into the DOM in the order they are clicked instead of toggling the class show/hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to the problem is, rather than hiding and showing elements (which relies on those elements being within the DOM already, then showing and hiding them as appropriate which retains their original order), to insert the relevant `<img />` elements on clicking the `<button>` elements.

In the HTML below I've stripped out much of the extraneous HTML in order to simplify the example, and I've converted your `<input type="button" />` elements into `<button>` elements, which allows those elements to contain HTML and allows us to use generated content in the pseudo-elements, `::before` and `::after`:

```js
// here we select all <button> elements that have a "data-src"
// attribute:
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-src]'),
    // creating a named function to handle inserting the
    // elements:
    insertImage = function() {
      // the 'this' is passed automatically from the later
      // use of EventTarget.addEventListener() method, here
      // we cache that within a variable:
      let clicked = this,

        // we retrieve the element, via its id, into which
        // we wish to append the elements:
        output = document.getElementById('gallery'),

        // we create an <img> element:
        image = document.createElement('img');

      // we use a template literal to set the 'src'
      // property-value to the 'https' protocol
      // coupled with the data-src attribute-value
      // retrieved via the Element.dataset API:
      image.src = `https://${clicked.dataset.src}`;

      // and append the <img> to the desired element:
      output.append(image);
    };

// here we iterate over the NodeList of <button> elements
// retrieved earlier, using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
buttons.forEach(
  // along with an Arrow function to the attach the
  // insertImage function (note the deliberate lack of
  // parentheses) via the EventTarget.addEventListener()
  // method:
  (btn) => btn.addEventListener('click', insertImage)
);
```

```css
/*
  using the ::before pseudo-element, with generated
  content, to add text to the button elements that
  have a data-src attribute:
*/
button[data-src]::before {
  content: 'Show image ' attr(value);
}

#gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 180px);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!--
  here we have three <button> elements, each with a data-src
  custom attribute that contains the src of the relevant image:
-->
<button type="button" value="A" data-src="i.stack.imgur.com/4CAZu.jpg"></button>

<button type="button" value="B" data-src="i.stack.imgur.com/SqYhm.gif"></button>

<button type="button" value="C" data-src="i.stack.imgur.com/a9xXV.png"></button>

<div id="gallery"></div>
```